# "not applicable for the arguments ..." issue when creating Java generics arrays, e.g., `T[]`, as both input and output of a method

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I am newbie to Java and now learning the Java generics. I encountered a issue when I tried to build a method with both input and output arguments of the generics type `T[]`.

## Example

---

Assuming we have a method `f` which aims to fetch the first `n` entries of an array `arr`. If the array consists of integers, we can implement it as below for example:

```
    public static int[] funcInt(int[] arr, int n) {
        int[] res = new int[n];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n) {
            res[i] = arr[i];
            i++;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Then, I am wondering whether we can step further by using `T[]` instead of `int[]` for the array `arr`, such that this method applies to arrays of other types. My attempt is below:

```
    public static <T> T[] Func(T[] arr, int n) {
        T[] res = (T[]) Array.newInstance(arr.getClass(), n);
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n) {
            res[i] = arr[i];
            i++;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

---

***However***, given an integer array `int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 3 };`:

- If I run `funcInt`, e.g., `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(funcInt(a, 3)));`, I can achieve the desired output

```
Note: test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[1, 2, 3]
```

- If I run `Func`, e.g., `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Func(a, 3)))`, errors pop up as below

```
test.java:36: error: method Func in class test cannot be applied to given types;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Func(a, 3)));
                                           ^
  required: T[],int
  found:    int[],int
  reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: int
    lower bounds: Object
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>Func(T[],int)
Note: test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

## Question

I have no clue what's wrong in my `Func` method with `T[]` and why is the error

> method Func in class test cannot be applied to given types

Could anyone explain a bit and correct me if I had misused `T[]` somewhere? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 issues:

1. An `int` can't really be generified, use Integer instead
2. You're using `arr.getClass()`, which will return the array type for T. Instead, use `arr.getClass().getComponentType()`, which will return T.
3. You're doing `i++` in the `res[i++] = arr[i]` part, which is equivalent to `res[i] = arr[i+1]`, and will shift all elements to the left once.

Here's a corrected solution:

```java
public static <T> T[] Func(T[] arr, int n) {
    T[] res = (T[]) Array.newInstance(arr.getClass().componentType(), n);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        res[i] = arr[i++];
    }
    return res;
}
```